# Collapsing item in JavaFX Tree View leaves some items improperly rendered

Tags: treeview, javafx-8

My JavaFX application uses Tree View and tree items are added dynamically added at different points while the program is running. The tree view does not render some tree items after expanding and collapsing items. The following images will make my point clearer.

[image: After expanding]

[image: After collapsing]

The first picturing shows the tree after expanding and the second picture show the same tree after collapsing. As you can see the item Plate does not get properly rendered.

Is this a JavaFX bug or have I done something wrong? Also is there a correct way to get it rendered correctly or a workaround if this happens to be a bug?

Comment: I think I've found the answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205586/javafx-treeview-not-refreshing-upon-shrinking-parent-showing-children-artifact).

Comment: I have the problem also

Comment: @MinhLe The problem is taking place because you haven't handled the case where `empty` is `true` in the `updateItem` method. Set the view to `null` as necessary.

Comment: Augn Thanks! I have applied it, it works well